# 502 Bad Gateway using ExpressJS and nginx for static files

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm try to run a expressJS app and using nginx on my digitalocean hosting account. I'm getting 502 bad gateway problem when i request static files

This is how my nginx config looks like

```
upstream app_x {
    server 127.0.0.1:2000;
}

# nginx server instance
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name humpyoutube.com, www.humpyoutube.com;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/x.log;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/HumpYoutube;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @node;
    }

    location @node {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://app_x;
    }
}
```

and my app.js looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('node-compass')({mode: 'expanded'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

var server = app.listen(2000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Please help this is bothering me for quite sometime

Comment: what do your logs say?

Comment: This error usually occurs when nothing listens needed port (in your case `2000`). Does your `app.js` start successfully? What do you see when you run `node app.js`?